# PHP sqlsrv query does not return the value

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have two tables:

**hosts**

```
+----+--------+
| ID | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | mycomp |
+----+--------+
```

**owner**

```
+----+--------+------+
| ID | hostID | name |
+----+--------+------+
| 1  | 1      | John |
+----+--------+------+
```

I need the owner of the host. This should be the query itself:

```
SELECT
  o.name
FROM
  owner o 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  hosts h ON h.ID=o.hostID
WHERE
  h.name = 'mycomp'
```

If I run the query anywhere (e.g. Flyspeed SQL Query) but in `PHP` using `sqlsrv` it returns the `owner` properly. In `PHP` I got no rows back. This is the code:

```
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$db, "UID"=>$usr, "PWD"=>$pwd);
$connection = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);
if(!$connection) {
  die('Unable to connect to the database.');
}
$host = "mycomp";
$owner = "";
$options =  array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$result = sqlsrv_query(
  $connection, 
  'SELECT
    o.name
  FROM
    owner o 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    hosts h ON h.ID=o.hostID
  WHERE
    h.name = ?', 
  array($host), 
  $options
);

if( $result == false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);

if (sqlsrv_num_rows($result) < 1)
{
    $owner = "n/a";
}
else {
    $temp = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
    $owner = $temp[0];
    sqlsrv_close($connection);
    $result = "";
}
echo $owner; //prints 'n/a'
```

Comment: So you got `n/a` or empty result?

Comment: @gofr1 The row count is 0, so I get `n/a` for `$owner`.

Comment: Have you tried to replace  `if (sqlsrv_num_rows($result) < 1)` to `if ($row_count < 1)`?

Comment: @gofr1 Yes, I have. But also `echo $row_count;` returns `0`. So, this is not an issue with the rest of the `PHP` code for sure, neither the query itself. This will be something with `sqlsrv`, I believe.

Comment: Sorry, if bothering with "simple" things, but sometimes there is a problem right with them :) Have you tried to `print_r($result)` after `sqlsrv_query`? Also check this: `if( $result == false ) {` musr have `===` instead of `==` (just watching my similar code with DB connection)

Comment: I think `==` should be enough, but it doesn't matter since `$row_count` is zero. `print_r($result)` => `Resource id #8Array ( [0] => [Name] => )`.

Comment: The one last thing come in my head is to check what is send in `$host` variable.

Comment: `$host = "mycomp";`

Comment: Just spitballing here, but have you tried a different cursor, say `SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC` ?

Comment: Have you tried using `sqlsrv_fetch_array` before `sqlsrv_num_rows`?

Comment: @ImClarky Just tried `SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC`.
@alalp Yes, I have.

Comment: And what are the results of `sqlsrv_fetch_array` ? Any rows or `null` or `false`?

Comment: Then you have a problem with your query or your query call. Maybe you can try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the beginning of your query. Or check if `sqlsrv_rows_affected($result)` returns anything.